# Joining text with IF functions

Tags: excel, if-statement, concatenation, ms-office

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet that contains first names, preferred first names, and last names. First Name, Preferred Name, and Last Name are all in separate columns.

I want to populate a 4th column with the persons full preferred name, Joining either First Name with Last Name or Preferred Name with Last Name. How would i achieve this in excel?

Below is an example of what I would like the finished product to resemble.

| First Name | Preferred Name | Last Name | Full Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John |  | Doe | John Doe |
| Billy | Bill | Clark | Bill Clark |
| Joseph |  | Clark | Joseph Clark |
| Mary | Bell | Doe | Bell Doe |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=IF(B2="",A2,B2) & " " & C2
```

So if B2 is blank we choose A2.  If B2 is not blank we choose B2. Then concatenate it with `" "` and whatever is in C2.

[image]

Comment: This Worked! thank you so much. Could you give me a rough run down on how this works so I can better understand?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Plan on doing so, But i just posted so i have to wait another 3 minutes before i can select this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [TEXTJOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) function, if your Excel version supports it:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,IF(B2="",A2,B2),C2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data starts in `A1`:

`=IF(B2="",CONCAT(A2," ",C2), CONCAT(B2, " ", C2))`

Comment: Hi this worked well like the other method scott put, Could you explain it a bit? I'm refreshing my Excel skills and it's been a while since i used IF functions

Comment: @teylyn Are you perhaps confusing `CONCAT` with the older `CONCATENATE`?